# Simpson-Tie Bolt Length

Tags: framing, code-compliance, foundation

I am in the middle of my kitchen remodel and the plans call for three Simpson Tie HDU2.5's to be installed.  It calls for the Simpson RFB#X5X16HDG (16" bolt) to be set no less than 9" in the foundation with SET-XP epoxy.  I have a 16" crawl space between the ground/foundation and the subfloor.

The question is:  What do I do with the 16" bolt that needs to be 28" in length if it is going to be set 9" in foundation, clear the 16" crawl space, and go through the sill and leave enough for the nut to attach?  Also, what size drill should I use for making the hole, 3/4"?

Thanks for any guidance...  below is a screenshot of the plan requirements.

[image: My Plans Callout]

Comment: I think your plans are wrong.  They have been drawn on the assumption the kitchen is on a solid (concrete) slab, not joists and flooring above a crawl space.  You need a quick redesign (which is going to involve fixing the sill plate to the joists).

Comment: Thank you, makes sense.  I have an email and call out to my architect this morning, but he hasn't responded and this is now holding up my project.  I would run down to the city but they are booked until next week.

Answer (score 3):

It has been confirmed it is an error in the plans.  Below is the correct callout for a raised subfloor.

[image]